# Need help to create a Previous and Next button in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button

Apologized for my English, Im not good at writing.
I have 3 swf file: **"Main.swf", "Frame1.swf", "Frame2.swf"** and 2 buttons: **"Previous"** and **"Next"** in the top layer of "Main.swf"

I need to load "Frame1.swf" when clicking the Next button and unload "Main.swf", but when "Frame1.swf" is loaded,"Main.swf" is keep on looping,and its lowly, its seems like spamming CPU memory usage...what coding i should used to solve it?

i did try my best to solve but fail (follow these link: [How to load swf file by clicking Next button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172555/how-to-load-swf-file-by-clicking-next-button)
and: [How to remove previous swf when enter new swf (AS3)......?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435628/how-to-remove-previous-swf-when-enter-new-swf-as3)
and a lot of link by google).
I guess because the previous swf file's memory not totally remove when enter another swf, new swf just replacing on top and keep playing.

And when the new swf is loaded, its on top so my "Previous" and "Next" button is gone. I think i should load swf into a MovieClip but i dont know how to.

I try to add code to a "Exit" button by using fscommand but nothing happened.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching SWFs... Well, this isn't exactly super beautiful, but you could try to load all external movies in the beginning and just stop and hide them if you don't need them. Clicking next would do something like

```
frame1.alpha = 0;
frame2.alpha = 1;
frame1.stop();
frame2.play();
```

This way you only have to load them once and don't have to worry about reloading them.

To prevent high memory/cpu usage while keeping things the way they are right now, try to debug your code. An easy way is to just try and trace() things from the SWFs to see if they have been properly deleted or not.

You can change movieclip's depth by using yourMC.setChildIndex(num); 0 is below everything else, numChildren-1 is on top of everything.

You can add an empty movieclip by using var clip:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); and then add child movieclips by using clip.addChild(yourChildClip); You can also just add them to a movieclip you created with the Flash authoring tool (if you're using that).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I try to load a Frame1.swf into MovieClip, but when its loaded, it keep playing (thisMovieClip.stop() not working). I try stopAll(), gotoAndStop(), but there is nothing.

`var thisMovieClip:MovieClip;
 
var thisLoader:Loader = new Loader();

thisLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, doneLoading);

 
thisLoader.load( new URLRequest("Frame1.swf") );
 
function doneLoading(evt:Event):void {

thisMovieClip = MovieClip(thisLoader.content);

stage.addChild(thisMovieClip);

thisMovieClip.stop();

}`

Comment: I found this: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035344/movieclip-not-stopping-always-looping** and try my best...but nothing happened. I can load a swf into MovieClip but i can't unload the previous swf. Its still running in the background....

Comment: I think there are 2 ways:
**First**: Load all external swf into a MovieClip and stop them, when click the button the swf will be play

**Second**: When I click the button the new swf will be loaded and unload the previous swf.

I really dont know what i should to do...